# What does $T_z\mathbb{R}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}$ in p. 2 of Huybrechts' book mean?

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I apologize for my lack of imagination and the likely silliness of this question, but what does $T_z\mathbb{R}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}$ mean [here](http://i48.tinypic.com/32zkmc7.jpg) (last paragraph)?

And how does that extension work?

Thank you.

Comment: He's just taking the complexification of the real tangent space to get the complexified tangent space. What precisely is your issue, understanding what the complexified tangent space "means", or what the algebra ($T_z\mathbb{R}^2$ tensored over $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{C}$) means?

Comment: I guess my issue is both. I'd appreciate a brief explanation or forwarding to material.

Comment: @Welterschmerz Henry Horton has given you the technical meaning about how to algebraically realize the complexified tangent space. A more down to earth definition is that it is the complex derivations at $z$ of $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{C})$ or that it is the germs at $0$ smooth maps $\mathbb{C}\to M$ sending $0$ to $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_z \Bbb R^2 \otimes \Bbb C$ is the complexification of the real vector space $T_z \Bbb R^2$. Essentially, this operation just changes the field of scalars from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$, where the complex multiplication is defined on simple tensors by
$$z(v \otimes w) = v \otimes (zw)$$
for $v \in T_z \Bbb R^2$ and $z, w \in \Bbb C$.

A linear map
$$T: U \longrightarrow V$$
between real vector spaces extends to a linear operator
$$T_{\Bbb C}: U \otimes \Bbb C \longrightarrow V \otimes \Bbb C$$
defined on simple tensors by
$$T_{\Bbb C}(u \otimes z) = T(u) \otimes z$$
for $u \in U$ and $z \in \Bbb C$.